# Melhor configuração do PHP-FPM para 4gb de ram?

Tags: php, linux, configuração, php-fpm

Preciso de uma ajuda para configurar meu PHP-FPM eu tenho EC2 na amazon c4.large

3.75 GB RAM
2 CORE

No meu servidor eu so tenho PHP-fpm,NGINX e um servidor ftp ligados, o MySql está em uma RDS.

Minha configuração do php-fpm atual

```
pm.max_children = 25
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_requests = 100
pm.process_idle_timeout = 40
rlimit_files = 131072
rlimit_core = unlimited
```

Quando começa horário de pico as children não aguenta e servidor começa ficar lento e cai da timeout.

Alguem pode me ajudar otimizar estas configurações ?

Comment: Sei que faz tempo, mas gostaria de comentar uma coisa importante, muitas vezes você pode até fazer uma ótima configuração, mas o problema é na web-aplicação e não no servidor em si. Muitas aplicações como Wordpress tem um alto consumo. Todavia CMS como wordpress tem plugins para cache, e mesmo que não seja um CMS, se for uma aplicação sua é provavel que use um framework, sendo assim pode procurar  uma solução em PHP para cache tanto front quando back :)

Answer (score 1):

O php-fpm separa os processos php em subprocessos, cada um deles é responsável por processar uma requisição php por vez. Usando um valor máximo de processo filhos do php-fpm é possível saber o valor máximo de memória que poderá ser consumido com base no valor do [memory_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Isso significa que,

> pm.max_children * memory_limit ~= Quantidade **máxima** de memória que poderá ser usada por uma pool php-fpm.

No seu caso, vamos supor que o valor de memory_limit seja 128M, então teremos:

> 25 * 128M ~= 3200M

A quantidade máxima de memória que seu php-fpm deve usar é de aproximadamente 3,2Gb, sendo uma máquina compartilhada com o Sistema Operacional e NGINX, o valor já estaria perto do limite.

Caso o seus scripts php consumam menos de 128M é possível aumentar a capacidade de requisições que esse servidor irá receber.

Para descobrir o quanto de memória que sua requisição está gastando vc pode criar um log:

```
 $initialMem = memory_get_usage();
 // ... Tudo aqui
 $finalMem = memory_get_peak_usage();
 error_log('Defina um label ou coloque o nome do arquivo usando __FILE__ '.($finalMem - $initialMem)/1024 . " Kbytes"); //Armazena no log o uso de memória
```

Vale lembrar que scripts php podem modificar esse valor usando a função init_set, se disponível.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Você pode elevar o valor de `pm.max_requests` para que um processo filho de php-fpm receba mais requisições antes de ser reiniciado e reduzir o `pm.process_idle_timeout` para 5 segundos (5s) para que o processo não fique tanto tempo ocioso aumentando um pouco a capacidade de obter requisições.

De certa forma, esta é uma estimativa, é necessário ajustar os parâmetros conforme sua demanda e a característica de sua aplicação.